# Cognito User Pool Federated Identity - cannot signin with social media

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I am using Cognito user pool with [Federated identity provider sign-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9ZAO.png) as authentication (Not Cognito -> Federated identities, seems it is a different thing with identity provider under user pool)

My use-case:

1. User can ONLY signup with email/phone + password
2. link with social media(s) after username password login

Expectation:
User can login with

- phone / email + password [ok]
- Google
- Facebook
- Apple ID

Currently using [AdminLinkProviderForUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html) to link federated users to an existing user profile, so far working well and all identities are able to add to User attributes.

All identity provider attribute mapping is set as below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQzRF.png

The issue I encounter is users unable to login with social media with the above setting, it goes to the pre-signup flow, seems Cognito cannot regcion the social media account (but the user exists in the user pool's User attribute - identities ).

```json
[
    {
        "userId": "dummy google id",
        "providerName": "Google",
        "providerType": "Google",
        "issuer": null,
        "primary": false,
        "dateCreated": 1655781381056
    },
    {
        "userId": "dummy facebook id",
        "providerName": "Facebook",
        "providerType": "Facebook",
        "issuer": null,
        "primary": false,
        "dateCreated": 1655781805086
    },
    {
        "userId": "dummy apple id",
        "providerName": "SignInWithApple",
        "providerType": "SignInWithApple",
        "issuer": null,
        "primary": false,
        "dateCreated": 1656475825054
    }
]
```

If add email in the mapping attribute, the login will work.

But it will overwrite the email attribute that the user used to create the account.

For example:
End-user create an account with email abc@example.com and password 123456,
then login link with google (xyz@example.com), and the email attribute will be changed, no longer able to user abc@example.com to login.

Does anyone have a similar experience? I wanna keep the origin email login when user create account, and able to login with social media.